# При запуске команды docker: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, unix, shell

```
$ sudo docker run -v $(pwd):/var/loadtest -it direvius/yandex-tank
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Команды взял с оф. инструкции https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html?highlight=entrypoint. OS Ubuntu

Comment: ну, к яндекс-танку вопрос не относится вообще никаким боком. кроме того, что один раз упоминается. // проверка: если убрать упоминание, то суть вопроса не изменится ни на йоту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вероятно, путь к текущему каталогу (возвращаемый встроенной в оболочку командой `pwd`), содержит пробелы или другие спец-символы.

если поменять имя текущего каталога затруднительно, можно, например, заключить весь параметр в двойные кавычки:

```
... -v "$(pwd):путь" ...
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: Казалось, что Ваш ответ ближе всех к решению, но такую ошибку я уже встречал: `docker run -v "$(pwd):/app" alpine` ... docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /app.